forward packets between TUN interface and physical interface
I'm attempting to create a remote access VPN from scratch and am currently developing a proof-of-concept for the server-side functionality that forwards data between tun0 and enp4s0.
Code for Allocating the TUN Interface
Here’s the code I’m using to allocate the TUN interface:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048

int tun_alloc(char *dev) {
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;

    if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        perror("Opening /dev/net/tun");
        return fd;
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI; 

    if (*dev) {
        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
    }

    if ((err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr)) < 0) {
        perror("ioctl(TUNSETIFF)");
        close(fd);
        return err;
    }

    printf("Allocated interface: %s\n", ifr.ifr_name);
    return fd;
}

void setup_interface(char *dev) {
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sockfd;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("Socket for interface configuration");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);

    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_UP | IFF_RUNNING;
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr) < 0) {
        perror("Bringing up interface");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Brought up interface: %s\n", dev);

    struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr;
    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.0.0.1", &addr->sin_addr);  // IP: 10.0.0.1

    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFADDR, &ifr) < 0) {
        perror("Assigning IP address");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Assigned IP 10.0.0.1 to interface: %s\n", dev);

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.255.0", &addr->sin_addr);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCSIFNETMASK, &ifr) < 0) {
        perror("Setting netmask");
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Set netmask 255.255.255.0 for interface: %s\n", dev);

    close(sockfd);
}

void read_packets(int tun_fd) {
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ssize_t nread;

    while (1) {
        nread = read(tun_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (nread < 0) {
            perror("Reading from TUN interface");
            close(tun_fd);
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Read %ld bytes from TUN\n", nread);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char tun_name[IFNAMSIZ] = "tun0"; 
    int tun_fd;

    tun_fd = tun_alloc(tun_name);
    if (tun_fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating TUN interface\n");
        return 1;
    }

    setup_interface(tun_name);

    read_packets(tun_fd);

    close(tun_fd);
    return 0;
}

Commands to Enable Forwarding
After setting up the TUN interface, I ran the following commands to enable forwarding between the interfaces:
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp4s0 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i enp4s0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT

Verification of Configuration
I verified that the configuration was applied correctly by checking the iptables rules:
sudo iptables -L -v -n 

Output:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  tun0   enp4s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     0    --  enp4s0 tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

For NAT, I checked:
sudo iptables -t nat -L -v -n

Output:

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
5  3537 MASQUERADE  0    --  \*      enp4s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

And the routing table:
sudo ip route show

Output:
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.122 metric 100  
10.0.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1  
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.122 metric 100 

Now I run the following command to check if the forwarding works:
ping -I tun0 192.168.1.100
I verified that this IP is accessible through enp4s0.
However, the ping hangs indefinitely.
I opened Wireshark and can clearly see that the ICMP packets are being sent out through the tun0 interface, but there is no traffic being forwarded to enp4s0.
Questions
I suspect there may be a misconfiguration or a blockage in the forwarding between the interfaces. I have checked the kernel logs and found no errors.
Or maybe I just misunderstood the concept of TUN. Please enlighten me!
What could be causing the forwarding issue between tun0 and enp4s0, and what steps can I take to troubleshoot or resolve the problem?
Thank you


Now I run the following command to check if the forwarding works:
ping -I tun0 192.168.1.100


This doesn't check forwarding. The -I option does not make the OS pretend that the packet needs to be forwarded as if it had just arrived from tun0.
It actually does the opposite – 'ping' sends the packet to tun0 (ignoring your routing table completely), where it is received by your C program, which 'read()'s the packet but then does nothing with it.
As far as I know, Linux doesn't have a standard method to inject packets as if they had been received from some interface, so in order to test forwarding, you need to actually send those packets from "the other end" of the interface – i.e. have your C program build an IP packet in memory and write() it to the /dev/net/tun device, at which point the OS will actually "receive" them through tun0.
If your goal is specifically to test iptables configuration – which has nothing TUN-specific – you could test it with a pair of virtual veth interfaces (they always come in pairs), e.g. ping -I veth1 would send the packet through veth1 and it would be looped back through veth2 as a received packet, allowing you to test veth2↔enp4s0.

It's probably necessary to use a new netns for the sending veth, so that the source IP wouldn't be considered a "local(host)" IP in the "default" netns.

thank you, i will try that :)

@TomYan: It shouldn't be a problem since the destination is another host reachable over eth0, not a local interface, but I forgot veth is L2 and not L3, so -I won't just work as easily.

Hey, I just wanted to give a huge thanks for your help! Your advice worked perfectly, and I was able to solve the issue.
